Mailchimp API v3 - Trying to Update a list-member using returns error 400
I'm having issues getting my Mailchimp API v3 integration working.
I'm able to add new members to a list, using the Add/Update or the Add endpoints.  But then if I try and Update that member (e.g. to change their Status to 'unsubscribed') I am getting the error:  status 400, Member Exists...Use PUT to...update list members".
I am making these calls via cURL commands, essentially - I am not using a library (JS, PHP, Ruby, etc.).  (The platform is FileMaker, FWIW - using the 'Insert from URL' step.)
{
"title":"Member Exists"
,"status":400
,"detail":"bogus_email@server.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members."
,"instance":"...42"
}

Yes, I am using 'PUT'.  I have tried this action using both the Update and the Add/Update endpoints.  Both return the same error.
URL:
https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<listID>/members/<Emailhash>

cURL  (the '-d' data element works - this is syntax particular to the platform I'm calling from):
    --user "APIKey:<mykeyhere>"
    -d @$Body_JSON

Body JSON:
{"email_address":"bogus_email@server.com","status":"unsubscribed"}

I have a number of other API calls working, including the 'add' function (as noted - which uses the POST verb, of course).  The Add function (on the Add/Update endpoint via 'PUT' verb) works fine as long as it is a brand new email being added.
Yes, I am using the Lower() form of the email address when creating the MD5 hash.  I have tried the call with using the email address directly in the endpoint URL (instead of the MD5 hash) and that also fails.
I also tried to use Postman to send the API calls, but was running into a weird issue where the URL didn't stick - it would show up as "https://undefinedvariable.api.mailchimp.com..." (or something similar) in the console, even if I hardcoded the URL to the correct endpoint (that is, I wasn't using a variable substitution to define the URL).
Thanks for your time in helping me out.

Got my problem solved.  Two things:

My MD5 hash function was broken, so that was the cause of most of the issues.
A workaround:  You can use the endpoint-form with the raw email in it, instead of the MD5 hash - so you don't have to worry about the hashing function.

'https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}?skip_merge_validation=<SOME_BOOLEAN_VALUE>'
or:
'https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members/{emailaddress}?skip_merge_validation=<SOME_BOOLEAN_VALUE>'
The hash version is what they spell out and recommend, but the documentation also says - in the description - that you can use the email address.  But, as noted, I got the hash version working, too.
